# iOS Master-Detail Application using Storyboards

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

Must be missing something really obvious here but how do you change the size of the table view that you create when using the Master-Detail template.

If I select the Table View in the Document Outline and then look in the Size Inspector the View height is greyed out.

What I'd like to do is have a smaller table view in the middle of the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to recreate MasterViewController as a UIViewController instead of UITableViewController, and add your (smaller) table view as a view in MasterViewController on your storyboard.
Don't forget to adopt UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols in your new MasterViewController class.